# Python OpenCV 3.4 VideoWriter Issue

Tags: python, opencv

I'm facing something particularly weird.

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')

for cls in classes:
    output_video.open( os.path.join( args.destinationDirForVideos, dirName + '.avi'), fourcc, 30.0, (640,480))
    #output_video = cv2.VideoWriter( os.path.join( args.destinationDirForVideos , dirName + '.avi' ),fourcc,30.0,(640,360))
    for frames in someImgFiles:
        output_video.write(frames)

    output_video.release()
    #del(output_video)
```

The pseudocode is as above. The video gets generated and saved properly for the first class in the loop and subsequent videos are simply not opened. I checked using output_video.isOpened(). I have tried both methods of initialization (commented and uncommented) and also tried to delete the object at the end of 1 iteration (1 cls). But I'm only able to write the first video.

Any explanation would help.

Python : 2.7.12

OpenCV : 3.4.0 (Installed through pip)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D')
for cls in classes:
    output_video = cv2.VideoWriter( os.path.join( args.destinationDirForVideos , dirName + '.avi' ),fourcc,30.0,(640,360))
    for frames in someImgFiles:
        output_video.write(frames)

    output_video.release()
```